# While Installing Plugin unable to download Issue in Cordova application

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

When I am trying to add plugin to cordova application using config file it showing error like **unable to download** what will be the problem how to solve this Issuse

[image]

Comment: Did you click the link below the error and use that information to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the plugins was renamed with different nomenclature from the one visual studio have for example **org.apache.cordova.geolocation has been renamed to cordova-plugin-geolocation**.

To enable the plugins in your project you have to follow the instruccions from here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/tips-and-workarounds/general/README.md#plugin-xml

But remember to use the new plugin name.

Comment: Actually I saw visual studio have the right nomenclature but for some reason it does not work with the config.xml designer. Also the version of the plugin is not need if you always want to get the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up adding the Plugin i wanted over the commandline with something like:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Then I added it again in VS2015 and it seems to have worked fine.